# How to print outer JSON attribute on each line with the inner ones?

Tags: json, jq

I have JSON like this:

```
{
  "files": [
    { "size": 3227238, "name": "file1.mp3" },
    { "size": 3737995, "name": "file2.mp3" }
  ],
  "id": "music"
}
```

And I want to print each file on its own line, but including the id from the outer element.

```
file1.mp3 music
file2.mp3 music
```

I can get the file attributes like this:

```
jq -r '.files | .[] | .name'
```

But how do I include the id on each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this filter:

```
"\(.files[].name) \(.id)"
```

This will yield a string for each of the files containing the name and the outer id.

You will probably want to get the raw output so don't forget the `-r` flag.

If you wanted to pull more than just the name from each of the files, you would need to make adjustments to the filter.  The key is to use `.[]` at most, once within any one part of the filter.  Depending on where you want each part in the string, there are a number of approaches you can take.

If they are all together in one part of your string, you can just add another string combining the properties you want:

```
"\(.files[] | "\(.name) \(.size)") \(.id)"
```

Otherwise, it would be easier to introduce a variable:

```
.id as $id | .files[] | "\(.name) \($id) \(.size)"
```

Comment: Just be careful when using multiple `.[]` in a single filter, you will get a cross product of all possible values. If you needed more properties of each of the files, the filter would have to be adjusted.

Comment: error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting $end
    (.files[].md5) (.id) [pointing at the second '(']

Comment: What does your command line look like? The backslashes might confuse the shell. Use single quotes for the filter. e.g., `jq -r '"\(.files[].name) \(.id)"'`

Comment: If I wanted to get the name and the size, is there a way to extend the filter, or is it just ````\(.files[].name) \(.files[].size)```` ?

Comment: You would have to make adjustments as I mentioned in an earlier comment. You will run into problems if you do that. I'll update in a bit on what you can do.

Comment: `jq -r '"\(.files[] | [.name, " ", .size | tostring] | add),\(.id)"'` seems to work